# How to PrePersist OffsetDateTime to Postgres with Jpa/Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to automatically save date to database.

I have `@Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class Audit {

    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void preCreate() {
        this.createdAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

And my entity with:

```
@Embedded
private Audit audit = new Audit();
```

I am catching this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: a null value in the created_at column violates the NOT NULL constraint
```

(translated from ru)

If I move this fields to my entity and add @PrePersist to both fields and write

```
private OffsetDateTime createdAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
private OffsetDateTime updatedAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
```

then it is working for me.

What I am doint wrong to save date to database?

Comment: `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` only work with entities. There is no such operation as updating/persisting an embeddable

Comment: @crizzis I found example with that way... so what should I do then, and what the reason of Embaddable if I cant do nothing except embed some fields to entity?

Comment: I did a little googling and I think you mean [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/prepersist-preupdate-embeddable-jpa-hibernate/), which suggests Hibernate does support entity listeners on embeddables. If that's the case, I stand corrected; I couldn't find anything on that functionality in the Hibernate docs, though.

Comment: As for the purpose of Embeddable, it's primarily what you said: to embed certain fields in the entity table, so that you could map a flat relational structure (all data in a single table) onto a non-flat object structure (entity with object properties)

Comment: @crizzis ok thanks